# Spark: How can I get every pair from two arrays efficiently?

Tags: java, apache-spark

Input is like

```
[K1, Tuple(Array A, Array B)]
[K2, Tuple(Array A, Array B)]
[K3, Tuple(Array A, Array B)]
```

What I want to do with input is that:

- *Key*: transform to value for each pair from value
- *Values*: make every possible pair between two arrays and transform to key

after this operation, I want to get this result:

```
[(A[0],B[0]), K1]
[(A[0],B[1]), K1]
[(A[0],B[2]), K1]
[(A[1],B[0]), K1]
[(A[0],B[0]), K2]
[(A[0],B[1]), K2]
[(A[0],B[0]), K3]
```

I used `flatMapToPair` to do this operation. `flatMapToPair` returns one output so I had to merge every key, value pair into some list like this:

```
[K1, Tuple(Array A(size 2),Array B(size 2))]
== flatMapToPair=>
ArrayList{[(A[0],B[0]),K1],[(A[0],B[1]),K1],[(A[1],B[0]),K1],[(A[1],B[1]),K1]}
```

However, in this situation, when input data is so large, output(ArrayList) is too large to handle with RDD (RDD size cannot be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in Spark). So, I need another way to do this avoiding large output.

Comment: Your desired output is missing `[(A[1],B[1]),K1]` for example, is that deliberate? And if so, how do you determine that this isn't needed?

Comment: I also don't know spark but assuming you want to build every possible pair the output size should almost be equal for anything besides an array list. So one option might be to employ a streaming approach, i.e. map only a part of the input, pass it to RDD and them continue with the next part of the input.

Comment: @Thomas I need [(A[1],B[1]),K1] as well. in example, that is omitted. If I understand second comment correctly, you mean pairing Array A with a part of Array B, right? Oh!!! I think it works!! Thank you so much, I will try that.

Comment: You could do that or just split at the keys, i.e. handle K1 first, then K2 etc.

Comment: I suppose you could try a flatMap first to make it into pairs of (K,Array A) and (K, Array B) and then try spark's cartesian product, but I am not sure about the handling

Comment: @GameOfThrows As I know, flatmap makes(returns) one output per a input.. Could you tell me how I can make (K,Array A) and (K,Array B)?

Comment: I mean something like mapping each K with a member of the Tuple, so something like rdd.flatMapValues(x=>x) should take each value K and map it with each Array A and B from the Tuple.

Comment: @ljhokgo Could provide some context? What do you want to do with the output? What are the types of A, B, K? How much distinct values do you expect in A, B?